# Access localhost API from a remote host using ssh

Tags: python, sockets, ssh, pexpect, python-sockets

I have an application running on a headless remote machine (ubuntu). This application contains an API communicating on localhost, port 4068. I can connect to this machine by ssh on port 22.

Working directly with python on the remote machine, I can use the sockets-client package and get in a couple of lines what I want:

```
#From within remote machine!
import socket
s = socket.socket()
s.connect(("127.0.0.1",4068))
s.send("help")
print(s.recv(1024))
#prints the API help
```

What I want is to do some analytics on my local machine by communicating with the remote API (which is really remote, not in the local network).

What I did so far was using `pxssh` and calling `telnet`. I guess it's not optimal, for sure it isn't for me. I would prefer an alternative using the sockets-client package or similar.

Here is a sample code of my solution

```
#From my local machine.
from pexpect import pxssh
import pexpect
#hostname, username and password are information to connect to ssh
p = pxssh.pxssh()
p.login(hostname,username,password)
query = r"telnet 127.0.0.1 4068"
p.sendline(query)
p.sendline("help")
p.expect("help")
p.expect([p.PROMPT,pexpect.EOF,pexpect.TIMEOUT])
print(p.before)
#prints the API help together with waste.
```

Note: I know I should use a regex in the expect function then print the matching string. Either way, it's not elegant and very complicated when you compare to simply using the sockets-client package.

Other solutions I considered but are less optimal:

- I could of course redirect the API port to a certain port of my
  switch/modem, but I am afraid it leads to security issues (I am no
  security expert, actually not even an IT guy). I could also write
- I could have my python program on the remote machine but this seems more complicated than using telnet via `pxssh`. Also it means I need to do package management and whatnots, so my solution is not portable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't know what you are using on the server side I am using pythons `http.server` here started like

```
python3 -m http.server
```

On the client side i am using [`sshtunnel`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/sshtunnel/0.1.2) with the following code:

```
from sshtunnel import SSHTunnelForwarder
import socket

# open ssh tunnel
server = SSHTunnelForwarder(
    '',
    ssh_username="",
    ssh_password="",
    remote_bind_address=('127.0.0.1', 8000)
)

server.start()

print('local port:', server.local_bind_port)  # show assigned local port
# work with `SECRET SERVICE` through `server.local_bind_port`.

#create an INET, STREAMing socket
s = socket.socket(
    socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
#now connect to the web server on port 8080
s.connect(('127.0.0.1', server.local_bind_port))
s.send(b'GET / HTTP/1.0 \r\n\r\n')
print(s.recv(1000))
s.close()

server.stop()
```

For your purpose of interacting with a telnet like shell you could use the python built-in [`telnetlib`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/telnetlib.html).

Comment: This is beautifull, thank you! I have no control on the server side, but it works the same (except I send "help", not "GET...").

Comment: No, SSHTunnelForwarder is exactly what I needed and was not aware of. I don't like using telnet, too much hassle.