# Do a query in a redis API with the terminal

Tags: api, redis

I have installed [SpliceAI Lookup API](https://github.com/broadinstitute/SpliceAI-lookup) on my Mac computer. This works ok but I want to use this API from a remote computer (via SSH). I am able to run the API remotely but I cannot do a query because I need to open the browser.

Can I do this remotely?

I have seen [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46694151/access-localhost-api-from-a-remote-host-using-ssh) but I don´t want to create a tunnel because I guess, I could do the same without the tunnel getting access remotely to the computer in a new terminal and do the query, couldn´t I? How can I do this?